# Is it possible to build a different output for the same TargetFramework in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to build two dlls using the same TargetFramework. I am using MSBuildSdkExtras to be able to have multiple TargetFramework `<TargetFrameworks>Xamarin.iOS10;MonoAndroid10.0</TargetFrameworks>` and conditional compilations for the source files, e.g. `<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid')) ">`.

However I want to be able to generate two different .dlls for MonoAndroid, with different source files, and can't see how to do this without replicating the .csproj file, along with a common .csproj for common source code.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new, user defined configuration type (in addition to `Debug` and `Release`). Use the configuration manager for this (easiest from the dropdown menu in the toolbar, where it says `Debug` or `Release`). Select the last entry to add new configurations. The downside is that maintaining this extra configuration may be cumbersome.

[image: Dropdown]